# Geth Providing error on its directory path

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, poa, geth-clique

I have initilize my node1 with my genesis file which worked fine command is 'geth --datadir node1/ init genesis.json'. But with same geth when I try to run this command

```
geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --rpc --rpcaddr '0.0.0.0' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,admin,miner' --ws --wsaddr '0.0.0.0' --wsport 8601 --wsapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,admin' --wsorigins * --rpccorsdomain *  --bootnodes 'enode://f6efbe327b816a3988517795dab11555e3b4488df1a146d37c885eecb40549da4fed1878ecd9fab0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2072f553bb51862ad78f8b13948de7cf02@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30310' --networkid 9XXX65 --gasprice '1'
```

To run the node then it provides me following error

```
invalid command: "node1"
```

Can anyone let me what is problem is about and how to resolve it? I am running it on AWS ec2 instance.

Comment: Try with `./node1` instead of `node1/`

Comment: @FlorianCastelain , I have tried all this method still getting same error .

Comment: It might be a problem with shell expansion of wildcards. Try escaping them or enclosing them in quotes `geth ... --wsorigins "*" ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a create `node1` folder `mkdir node1` first and then use  `~/node1/`